# Changing python from 2.7 to 2.6 for omniidl

Tags: python, python-2.7, omniorb

I have downloaded the omniORB4.1.6 pre-compiled with msvc10. I have python 2.7 and everything seems to work fine. I want to know how i can tell my omniidl to use my python 2.6 installation instead of 2.7. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can't and shouldn't.  it is compiled specifically for 2.7.  that's why "2.7" appears in the download file name.

if you want to use a different python, download the source package and build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to rename the folder? like from python27 to python271? Because it looks like omniidl is always looking for C:/python27.